# What does "num_examples: 2000" mean in TensorFlow object detection config file?

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

In the sample pipeline config file of TensorFlow object detection, there is this snippet:

```py
  eval_config: {
    num_examples: 2000
    # Note: The below line limits the evaluation process to 10 evaluations.
    # Remove the below line to evaluate indefinitely.
    max_evals: 10
  }
```

Does "num_examples" mean each evaluation run uses the same first 2000 images, or it treats the test set as a circular buffer and uses different 2000 images each time?

Answer (score 4):

Actually this means only the **same** top *num_examples* samples in your evaluation dataset will be used in each run of evaluation.

Answer (score 2):

num_example is equal to the number of test images you are feeding into the API

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR** Circular buffer if enough `num_epochs` and no `shuffle`

I believe it works in "collaboration" with the input reader config. If in the `eval_input_reader` you set `num_epochs` to 1, then it will process the first 2000 images from the input queue, provided the `shuffle = false`, otherwise some random 2000 images. If you don't have 2000 images, it will probably fail, as the queue is emptied.

The relevant code is [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/1e2ada24c6734b3f6f4e09cb98f66f3aad68de76/research/object_detection/eval_util.py#L214) and [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/1e2ada24c6734b3f6f4e09cb98f66f3aad68de76/research/object_detection/evaluator.py#L144)

Comment: The default value of `num_epochs` in `InputReader` protobuf [is 0](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/1e2ada24c6734b3f6f4e09cb98f66f3aad68de76/research/object_detection/protos/input_reader.proto#L36). If I understand you correctly, in this case, the test set will be cycled through indefinitely at 2000 images a time, yes?